# htaccess redirect - too many redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite

> www.domain.co.uk/store?cat=57

to

> www.domain.co.uk/store/57

but I keep getting a 'too many redirects' error. I've got the following in my htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=([^./]*)$
RewriteRule ^store\.php$ /store/%1? [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^store/([^./]+)$ store.php?cat=$1 [L]
```

The redirect works if I comment out the bottom line, however this then stops my pages loading properly.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Hope my post will be helpful..

Comment: What url is causing **too many redirect error** ?

Comment: @starkeen Last two `RewriteRule` are causing `too many redirects` like `example.com/store.php?cat=1` this will redirect to `example.com/store/1`  and then  `example.com/store/1` will redirect to  `example.com/store.php?cat=1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+store\?cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /store/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^store/([^./]+)/?$ store?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Nice answer croises.

Comment: @starkeen Thank you very much !

Comment: @Croises, I implemented the code exactly as above, but it doesn't redirect - if I put in www.domain.co.uk/store?cat=57, it stays as www.domain.co.uk/store?cat=57. The pretty url works fine, it just doesn't redirect to it.

Comment: It was with `.php`in your htaccess in the question. I change my code now with that. Clear your cache and try again.